# Trying to catch an error in Dart in parent class

Tags: generics, flutter, dart

Im trying to make a generic way of catching API errors in my base view model, but its not working as expected.

[image: Code example]

I want my error to be set in the super BaseModel (line 24 and 26) but somehow it is not triggering those lines of code.

I think it's my limited knowledge of how Dart works. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at code, you want to invoke async operation and catch its errors and set state accordingly. But you are not really waiting for the async operation to over. `apiCall` just returns `Future`

One way to get the same affect

```
Future<T> apiCall<T>(ValueGetter<Future<T>> actualCall) async {
  try {
    setState(ViewState.Busy);
    T result = await actualCall; // Here you are actually waiting for opeation to be over
    return result;
  } on ErrorResponse catch(errorResponse) {
    error = errorResponse;
  } catch (e) {
    error = ErrorResponse.fromMessage('unknown');
  }
  setState(ViewState.Idle);
  return Future.error(error); // Or you can return Future.value(null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, working perfectly now. Was really overthinking this :-)

Comment: You could also just do `return await actualCall();` but that's a nit.